No Markup Tools in Notes?
My problem is similar to the Apple Discussion markup tool on iPad is missing. There are no Markup Tools in Notes. I have tried a hard reset, updating to iPadOS 17.7, checking every button mentioned in every tutorial, setting notes for iCloud, and restarting.
I cannot draw in Notes. This is very frustrating. This is on IPad Air 11-inch (M2).

What is „the latest OS version“?

@nohillside Edited: 17.7

17.7 isn‘t the latest :-) Anyway, I assume the pencil works in other apps?

@nohillside yes. It works in mail for example. It seems it has been removed in Notes. Notability has it and it works very well... I'll likely just use that.
